# Pass additional properties to an EditorTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

How do I pass some additional properties to an `EditorTemplate`?

I want to use it like this (kind of pseudo code):

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ReturnFlight, new { additionalViewData = new { FlightType = FlightType.Return } })
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.OutboundFlight, new { additionalViewData = new { FlightType = FlightType.Outbound } })
```

FlightTemplate:

```
<h1>FLight @Model.FlightNumber</h1>
@if(FlightType == FlightType.Outbound)
{
    // Display stuff for outbound flights
}
else if(FlightType == FlightType.Return)
{
    // Display stuff for return flights
}
@Form.TextboxFor(m => m.Destination)
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You pretty much have it already - you can pass additional view data in exactly this way, using [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406462(v=vs.118).aspx). You just need to use it in your editor template. Remember values in the `ViewData` dictionary are also available in the dynamic `ViewBag` object.

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ReturnFlight, new { FlightType = FlightType.Return })
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.OutboundFlight, new { FlightType = FlightType.Outbound })
```

**FlightTemplate**

```
<h1>Flight @Model.FlightNumber</h1>
@if(ViewBag.FlightType == FlightType.Outbound)
{
    // Display stuff for outbound flights
}
else if(ViewBag.FlightType == FlightType.Return)
{
    // Display stuff for return flights
}
@Form.TextboxFor(m => m.Destination)
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast and great answer, missed the ViewBag part and it's working now.

Comment: Nice, but how to do it for tag helpers? <editor asp-for="MyTrip.ReturnFlight" />

Comment: TagHelpers work completely differently to HTML helpers, but to answer the question, you pass your data as attributes. You can create equivalent properties in your TagHelper to help coding and creating a strongly-typed mapping but unspecified attributes are serialized and available as strings ,e.g. `<MyTag id=@Model.ID custom-value="test" />`